# View of 3D Cursor and Origin

Tags: 3d-cursor

Where in the settings can I add or remove these axes for the 3D cursor and Origin?

[image]

Comment: Which Blender version, please?

Comment: Blender version. 4.0.1 I found this cool thing (for me) when I saw the MESHmachine 0.14.1 tutorial, but when I wanted to set up my Startup file like this, I couldn't find where to enable it.

Comment: If those axes are produced by MESHmachine you'll have to ask the developer or look in the docs as we can't answer questions about third-party addons here. However the section about its settings is [here](https://machin3.io/MESHmachine/docs/preferences/).